# Knockoutjs: observablearray replace not update html template

Tags: javascript, python, django, knockout.js

I pass parameters to the script of views

```
var commentModel =  function(config) {
    var self = this;
    self.comments = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(config.comments));
...
```

I need to control the visibility of a comment.There is a visible parameter, which changes when you change the visibility.
I first realized by push and remove

```
  self.CommentVisible = function(id,visible){
        temp = self.comments.remove(function(item) { return item.id == id }) ; 
        temp[0].show_folded = visible;
        self.comments.push(temp[0]);  
        self.sortByPath();
        return false;
    }
```

Now I try to be rewritten using replaсe. Element it replaces, but it does not update the template. Advise me what to do?

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle for this with the relavant code? http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Are the items in the observable array also observables?